# python - convert string to int with space delimiter

Tags: python

I'm using some library which converts data to other format.
As I don't want to debug this library, I'd like to solve the solution on my code.

The input is integer and maybe `-1`. In this case and the library output is  `- 1`.
I need to compare this integer if this is positive or negative. How can I handle the `- 1` for this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string `x="- 1"` and want to convert it to int, `eval(x)` works.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = "- 1"
>>> intx = eval(x)
>>> print(type(intx))
<class 'int'>
>>> print(intx)
-1
```

Comment: at least use `ast.literal_eval` its marginally safer :) good answer though

Answer (score 0):

```
int("- 1") # nvm this doesnt work in py3
```

i think works  (but not `float('- 1')` )

you could also just remove all the spaces

```
float("- 1".replace(" ",""))
```

Comment: lol weird it works in py2 ... i guess they got rid of that in py3